# Pymongo Updating Collections with appending list values

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo-3.x

New to learning about mongodb. I've read the quickstart documentation and the W3 stuff already
My question is about how to (best) do the following two things:

Case 1:

```
{"_id":'mySpecifiedID',
"PersonA": ['pasta','pizza','corn'],
"PersonB": ['pizza','hotdog'],
"PersonC": ['tacos']
}
```

I want to append the element "pie" to the list corresponding to "PersonB"
I know I can find() and get the full existing list-value for "PersonB" and append it to that in memory and then update the document. But I was wondering if there was a way to directly put the value, rather than the expensive search and return and append and update way.

Case 2:

```
{"_id":'mySpecifiedID',
"PersonA": {"2020-02-01":['pasta','pizza','corn'],
           "2020-02-02":['potato','kraut']},
"PersonB": {"2020-02-01":['pizza','hotdog','corn'],
           "2020-02-02":['duck','nuggets']}
}
```

I want to append to the value corresponding to "PersonB"["2020-02-02"]
I'm not sure how these items are accessible/updatable via PyMongo. Is there a way to only input food items that don't already exist in the array? Without reading everything out first?

More generally, coming from a background of relational databases. I'm not sure what best practice is here. Should I treat a document more like a transaction, i.e. a row in a table? Or more like a table, and the collection as a schema?

I know they don't perfectly parallel but just trying to understand

Comment: "_New to learning about mongodb..._" Points to note. (1) It is not a good practice to have _dynamic_ (or variable field names. Querying and updating operations can become complex as the data grows. E.g.: `"PersonA": ['pasta','pizza','corn']` is more usable if you can store person related info as an array of person objects: `persons: [ { 'name': 'PersonA', 'junk_food': [ 'pizza', 'pasta' ] }, { 'name': 'PersonB', ... }, ... ]`.

Comment: (2) To work with array fields, MongoDB has _array operators_ for querying, projection, updating, etc. [Query Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/operator/query/#array), [projection operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/operator/query/#projection-operators) and [update operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/operator/update/#array). In addition. there are also Aggregation Array and Set operators to work with arrays.

Comment: As you are familiar with SQL, this can be useful to you: [SQL to MongoDB Mapping Chart](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/sql-comparison/index.html).